# Java - Проблема с проверкой массива;

Tags: java

Всем доброго времени суток! 
Возникла проблема с проверкой массива на языке программирования java. Кратко: Есть переменная для ввода пользователя, есть массив, и есть if ветка, и да.. Есть объект random . 
Пользователь вводит слово : Привет (Должна пройти проверка if)
После проверки массива, вызывается функция вывода сообщения пользователю(Из второго массива, это должно быть рандомно);

1. Как правильно записать массив?(И что бы в коде выглядело нормально);
2. Как сделать проверку массива в if? (Я использовал equals(); );
3. Как правильно выводить рандомную фразу из массива? (Указание массива с переменной рандома не работает);

Кусочек кода(порезанный):

```
String setscan = scans.nextLine();//Считывает ввод пользователя;
    setscan = setscan.replaceAll(" +", "");//Игнорирует пробелы при вводе;

String[] dict_one = {
            "Добрый день", "Привет", "Здравствуй"};

Random rnd = new Random(); //Создаем новый объект класса Random;
        int rnds = rnd.nextInt(2); // Генерируем числа от 0 - 2;

//Словарь 1, проверка - ответ;
        if (setscan.equals(dict_one)) {
            System.out.println(dict_one[rnds]);
```

Буду очень благодарен! Примечания: На форуме я новичок, так же как и в java;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (Arrays.asList(dict_one).contains(setscan))
  System.out.println(dict_one[rnds]);
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо, все работает.